# find characters that are NOT letters, numbers or underscores

Tags: regex

Is there a way to use Regex to isolate characters that are NOT letters, numbers or underscores?

Comment: Define `isolate`; I suppose it's not the same as `match`, as otherwise it's quite a trivial task. )

Comment: isolate means match in this context, oh mighty SO pedant.

Comment: Ahh man, I'm sorry. Your negativity will certainly teach me a lesson. No one will ever find this question useful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try code like this: `/\W/`

Answer (score 1):

Yes.  Most regex implementations support this construct: **[^abc]**  where everything after the ^ character is something not to match.  In some implementations, this will work:

```
[^[:alnum:]_]
```

The **alnum** class is safer to use than a range because ranges make assumptions about the lexical order of the character set.

Answer (score 0):

Yes. [Read up on some regex basics, please.](http://www.regular-expressions.info/tutorial.html)

I don't really know what you mean by "isolate", but this will match any character that is not a letter, number or an underscore:

```
\W
```

And this will match any consecutive string of those characters:

```
\W+
```